# $\arg\max$ in the dual norm of the nuclear norm

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, matrix-analysis, convex-analysis

Given a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n},$  then the **spectral** norm is defined by

$$\left \| X\right\| := \max\limits_{i \in \{1, \dots, \min\{m,n\}\} }\sigma_i (X)$$

whereas the **nuclear** norm is defined by

$$\left \| X \right \|_* := \sum\limits_{i=1}^ {\min\{m,n\}} \sigma_i (X)$$

It is a well-known fact that [the dual norm of the spectral norm is the nuclear norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1158798). This implies that

$$\|M\| = \sup_{\|X\|_*\leq 1} \langle M, X \rangle$$

where the inner product is defined by $\langle A, B \rangle := \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(A^TB)$. Given a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n},$  how to find a matrix $X^*$ such that the following holds?

$$ X^* \in \arg\sup_{\|X\|_*\leq 1} \langle M, X \rangle$$

Comment: Solving the problem with CVXPY, as it is a convex program, should help. Are you looking for a more theoretical treatment of the problem?

Comment: @DSM both actually. I am comfortable with python but I haven't used that library before. Is this is easy to solve using CVXPY?

Comment: import cvxpy as cvx <newline>
import numpy as np <newline>
N = 5 <newline>
X = cvx.Variable((N,N)) <newline>
M = np.random.randn(N,N) <newline>
prob = cvx.Problem(cvx.Maximize(cvx.trace((M.T)@X)), [cvx.normNuc(X)<=1]) <newline>
prob.solve() <newline>
print(prob.status) <newline>
print(prob.value) <newline>
print(X.value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is $X^* = uv^*$ where $u$ and $v$ are the left and right singular vectors of $M$ associated with the largest singular value. If the largest singular value has multiplicity larger than $1$, the argsup is a convex set whose extreme points are the matrices of the form described above.

Comment: Thanks! You are absolutely right! I will add a proof here in case someone is looking for it in the future:

Suppose $X^*=uv^*$ where $u$ and $v$ are the left and right singular vectors of $M$ associated with the largest singular value. To show that $X^*$ attains the optimum, it suffices to show that $\langle M, X^*\rangle = \|M\| = \sigma_{max}$. But this follows from the cyclicity of the trace:
$trace(M^*uv^*) = trace(V^*\Sigma U u v^*) = trace(v^*V^*\Sigma U u)  =  \sigma_{max}$